# Issue in @selector of Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, selector

[mobile_Obj AuthenticateMobileServer:self action:@selector(Handler:) AccountNO:@"123" UserName:@"Sun" Password:@"123***"];

In the above method call , can we have two threads running simultaneously??

One thread running: AuthenticateMobileServer method

Second thread runnig: Handler method

Please let me knw is it possible or not, if so how to create thread for each of them?

Thank You.

Comment: I have noticed that you are asking a lot of questions, mainly about Objective-C and iPhone development. Have you read any books or online tutorials about iPhone development? Many of the 117 questions that you have asked are answered in any good book about Objective-C.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you could create a method that to be called by `@selector` which creates the threads instead.

Take a look at the [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) docs, as well as [this tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/).